# Automatic merge in Github repos with Snyk

Tags: snyk

I have snyk integrated with my github repos which use npm, and it's a nice free tool to detect vulnerabilities in the repos, but I'm getting constant emails about updates in `package.json` and for simple things as a patch version update in a unimportant dependency.

Is there a possibility for the snyk account to automatically not only open Pull Requests, but also merge them without my intervention, as long as they pass the test?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done for the repo via GitHub itself, by checking the "Allow auto-merge" option:

[image: GitHub auto merge screenshot (repo settings)]